# Proper modeling to sculpting process

Tags: modeling, workflow, sculpting, optimization

So here is the issue I am facing. I first model my ... well.. model and I then bring it to sculpting and at around 1milion+ polygons ( or tris and other stuff) I start getting really laggy. I mean my machine is okay, I am a programmer so it's decent but the GPU is mediocre at best, but I am not sure that has that big of an effect in this.
Specs: AMD Ryzen 7 2700 Eight-Core Pro, 16GB Ram, SSD, B450M DS3H-CF GIGABYTE motherboard, Radeon RX560

My process is as follows. I create a low poly model

[image]
After that I subdivide it on around 3-4 viewport, I join the stuff that needs to be connected (the meter and the glove) via CTRL + J I believe, and then go into sculpting with Dynamesh enabled on 50 and constant detail. I get to this

[image]

Now, this gets laggy even tho it isn't even that high, I want to try and remesh it but remeshing is awful, using 0.1m voxels is horrible and wrecks my sculpt while bringing that down makes the lag even crazier. I'd appreciate any tips on how to make this process smoother and more proper. And if the shitty GPU is at fault, can you still please share the proper workflow regardless if the GPU can handle it or not? (I've seen some videos where they sculpt with ~5million polys easy)

Any additional info I'll provide if needed

Thank you very much!

Comment: in the second screen you are in edit mode, not in sculpt mode. That's the problem: edit mode is really slow with a complex mesh. is it slow also in sculpt mode?

Comment: Yes it is, it's quite slow in the sculpt mode as well, not just slow, but rather laggy.

Comment: I suspect that 50 as details level is really huge. try to stick to 20 or 30